# Flutter: Create a timeline UI

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to make timeline UI like below:

[image]

---

**But i end up doing following:**

[image]

I want to increase the height of vertical Separator when no of lines of my Description text increases. How should i do that ?

Here is the [link for the code](https://github.com/tusharspol/myFlutterApp/blob/master/main.dart)

Answer (score 42):

I like Osama's answer too but here's my quick custom implementation. It uses a `CustomPainter` to draw the lines.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Timeline extends StatelessWidget {
  const Timeline({
    Key? key,
    required this.children,
    this.indicators,
    this.isLeftAligned = true,
    this.itemGap = 12.0,
    this.gutterSpacing = 4.0,
    this.padding = const EdgeInsets.all(8),
    this.controller,
    this.lineColor = Colors.grey,
    this.physics,
    this.shrinkWrap = true,
    this.primary = false,
    this.reverse = false,
    this.indicatorSize = 30.0,
    this.lineGap = 4.0,
    this.indicatorColor = Colors.blue,
    this.indicatorStyle = PaintingStyle.fill,
    this.strokeCap = StrokeCap.butt,
    this.strokeWidth = 2.0,
    this.style = PaintingStyle.stroke,
  })  : itemCount = children.length,
        assert(itemGap >= 0),
        assert(lineGap >= 0),
        assert(indicators == null || children.length == indicators.length),
        super(key: key);

  final List<Widget> children;
  final double itemGap;
  final double gutterSpacing;
  final List<Widget>? indicators;
  final bool isLeftAligned;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final ScrollController? controller;
  final int itemCount;
  final ScrollPhysics? physics;
  final bool shrinkWrap;
  final bool primary;
  final bool reverse;

  final Color lineColor;
  final double lineGap;
  final double indicatorSize;
  final Color indicatorColor;
  final PaintingStyle indicatorStyle;
  final StrokeCap strokeCap;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final PaintingStyle style;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
      padding: padding,
      separatorBuilder: (_, __) => SizedBox(height: itemGap),
      physics: physics,
      shrinkWrap: shrinkWrap,
      itemCount: itemCount,
      controller: controller,
      reverse: reverse,
      primary: primary,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final child = children[index];
        final _indicators = indicators;

        Widget? indicator;
        if (_indicators != null) {
          indicator = _indicators[index];
        }

        final isFirst = index == 0;
        final isLast = index == itemCount - 1;

        final timelineTile = <Widget>[
          CustomPaint(
            foregroundPainter: _TimelinePainter(
              hideDefaultIndicator: indicator != null,
              lineColor: lineColor,
              indicatorColor: indicatorColor,
              indicatorSize: indicatorSize,
              indicatorStyle: indicatorStyle,
              isFirst: isFirst,
              isLast: isLast,
              lineGap: lineGap,
              strokeCap: strokeCap,
              strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
              style: style,
              itemGap: itemGap,
            ),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: double.infinity,
              width: indicatorSize,
              child: indicator,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: gutterSpacing),
          Expanded(child: child),
        ];

        return IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children:
                isLeftAligned ? timelineTile : timelineTile.reversed.toList(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class _TimelinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  _TimelinePainter({
    required this.hideDefaultIndicator,
    required this.indicatorColor,
    required this.indicatorStyle,
    required this.indicatorSize,
    required this.lineGap,
    required this.strokeCap,
    required this.strokeWidth,
    required this.style,
    required this.lineColor,
    required this.isFirst,
    required this.isLast,
    required this.itemGap,
  })  : linePaint = Paint()
          ..color = lineColor
          ..strokeCap = strokeCap
          ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
          ..style = style,
        circlePaint = Paint()
          ..color = indicatorColor
          ..style = indicatorStyle;

  final bool hideDefaultIndicator;
  final Color indicatorColor;
  final PaintingStyle indicatorStyle;
  final double indicatorSize;
  final double lineGap;
  final StrokeCap strokeCap;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final PaintingStyle style;
  final Color lineColor;
  final Paint linePaint;
  final Paint circlePaint;
  final bool isFirst;
  final bool isLast;
  final double itemGap;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final indicatorRadius = indicatorSize / 2;
    final halfItemGap = itemGap / 2;
    final indicatorMargin = indicatorRadius + lineGap;

    final top = size.topLeft(Offset(indicatorRadius, 0.0 - halfItemGap));
    final centerTop = size.centerLeft(
      Offset(indicatorRadius, -indicatorMargin),
    );

    final bottom = size.bottomLeft(Offset(indicatorRadius, 0.0 + halfItemGap));
    final centerBottom = size.centerLeft(
      Offset(indicatorRadius, indicatorMargin),
    );

    if (!isFirst) canvas.drawLine(top, centerTop, linePaint);
    if (!isLast) canvas.drawLine(centerBottom, bottom, linePaint);

    if (!hideDefaultIndicator) {
      final Offset offsetCenter = size.centerLeft(Offset(indicatorRadius, 0));

      canvas.drawCircle(offsetCenter, indicatorRadius, circlePaint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

You'd call it something like:

```dart
Timeline(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(height: 100, color: color),
    Container(height: 50, color: color),
    Container(height: 200, color: color),
    Container(height: 100, color: color),
  ],
  indicators: <Widget>[
    Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
    Icon(Icons.backup),
    Icon(Icons.accessibility_new),
    Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
  ],
),
```

[image: An Image of a timeline mobile ui]

Comment: This is the perfect answer. I was looking to make Google Maps Route UI and this is exactly what I needed. Thank You!!

Comment: @Nolence I do like your answer too ^_^.

Comment: Nolance can you please updated the example with the icon being top align rather than center align?

Comment: How to get this sort of UI from the Jsonresponse, I'm using by adding a parent widget to the Timeline as the ListView.builder but can get the content and the icon part not the line connecting them/the start or end point

Comment: This is really helpful to get it define in our application and use as we want and we can also make changes to it as per our need. Thanks to share.

Comment: This is really helpful. Perfect answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is the best answer I have found. Also, what should I do to change the timeline to dotted? I tried a lot but not able to do it.

Answer (score 13):

```
 new ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return new Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0),
                          child: new Card(
                            margin: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                            child: new Container(
                              width: double.infinity,
                              height: 200.0,
                              color: Colors.green,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        new Positioned(
                          top: 0.0,
                          bottom: 0.0,
                          left: 35.0,
                          child: new Container(
                            height: double.infinity,
                            width: 1.0,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                          ),
                        ),
                        new Positioned(
                          top: 100.0,
                          left: 15.0,
                          child: new Container(
                            height: 40.0,
                            width: 40.0,
                            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            child: new Container(
                              margin: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                              height: 30.0,
                              width: 30.0,
                              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  color: Colors.red),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: 5,
                )
```

the output will be like this image [image]

Comment: Hope there is someone could explain why `height: double.infinity,` is not taking infinite height. This method works perfectly, but I could not figure out why this works logically.

Comment: @Tokenyet `double.infinity` means it will take all the space allowed by the parent. But you're right that it is not needed here, it has no effect. As the `Container` is wrapped in a `Positioned` widget, for which both the `top` and `bottom` properties are non-null, the `Container` will be forced to have exactly the height required to satisfy both constraints. So whatever the height you will set to the container it will be sized from top `0.0` to bottom `0.0`. To have any effect here, you would need to set a `height` for the `Positionned` widget and remove either `top` or `bottom` property.

Comment: Wow! The `top:0, bottom:0` to force the Container to inherit height here blew my mind tbh. Very nice trick. Thanks for the share. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

For those who are scrolling here to find an easy way to implement timelines, now you can do this easily with [timeline_tile](https://github.com/JHBitencourt/timeline_tile).

Check out this specific delivery layout:

[image]

Or this weather timeline:

[image]

Also, the [beautiful_timelines](https://github.com/JHBitencourt/beautiful_timelines) repository contains some examples built with this package.

[Web demo](https://jhbitencourt.github.io/beautiful-timelines/#/)

Comment: This is great. Built one with just a few lines. Here's an example: ```main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 4,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return TimelineTile(
          isFirst: index == 0,
          isLast: index == 3,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}```

Comment: It should be noted that this package contains many incompatible/outdated packages as of Nov 2022 for both Flutter 2 & 3. Some of the updates can break things when mixing a Flutter 2.x project

Answer (score 2):

There is other, more native and scalable way. Some solutions proposed fixed position/size values which is not really scalable if we want to have consistent experience on multiple devices with different screen resolutions.

Let me give you the mental model how to approach this problem. Let's pick this UI design that we would like to code with Flutter framework:

[image]

Seems intimidating? Which `Widget`s should we use? Those are really valid questions. After investigations and checking Flutter documentation it clearly looks that Flutter creators clearly focused on nice, easy examples providing simple UI solutions. This is not right. The timeline is not a simple one and we need to find tools on our own.

Let's break the problem into subproblems. First, let's just focus on a **single item**. We know that if we solve a problem for this one, we just can repeat such item with the help of `ListView.builder` or `Column`.

Single item approach:

[image]

The item can be divided into two sections. We can create a `Column` with `.min` height and have two `Row`s as children. The rows are:

- **Red** - Top one containing the circle (`Container`/`Icon`) and the text (`Text`)
- **Blue** - Bottom section containing the vertical line `Container` and the item (`Card`/`Material`/`Row`)

Red is simple. It is a `Row` with `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center` having the following children:

- a dot
- a horizontal separator
- text

The problem arises with a **Blue** one. Let's use a similar approach and code it as `Row` with vertical line as first item, and `Card` as a second one.

And now we arrive with a problem which Flutter devs were not that willingful to share with us.

The problem:

[image]

The **Green** section is the content that we want to put in the timeline. We surely know that if we put some text, it will scale bigger for smaller devices or if the end user increases the font. Clearly speaking, we cannot make this **Green** item with fixed height.

And now, the question arrives:

> How to make the Violet line to have the same height as the dynamic
> changing **Green** section?

A solution is `IntrinsicHeight`. It is a perfect Widget for such cases.
Docs state:

```
/// This class is useful, for example, when unlimited height is available and
/// you would like a child that would otherwise attempt to expand infinitely to
/// instead size itself to a more reasonable height.
```

What is reasonable for them? Hard to say. Nevertheless:

```dart
return IntrinsicHeight(
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          _renderLine(),
          _renderHorizontalSeparator(),
          _renderTimelineItem(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Such approach makes `IntrinsicHeight` child, which is `Row`, and other children "downstream" not to fill the entire height.

So for `_renderTimelineItem()` it is simple -> just a regular `Card` with item.

But the `_renderLine()` should be like this:

```dart
  Widget _renderLine(Color color) => Container(
        color: color,
        height: double.infinity, // this is an equivalent's to Android' MATCH_PARENT
        width: 1,
      );
```

And that's it. The problem was reduced to "How to make line expand to some sibling dynamic-height `Widget`".

One thing worth noticing. They write in documentation for `IntrinsicHeight`:

```
/// This class is relatively expensive, because it adds a speculative layout
/// pass before the final layout phase. Avoid using it where possible. In the
/// worst case, this widget can result in a layout that is O(N²) in the depth of
/// the tree.
```

Really? Avoid where possible? So should we stick with fixed values (worst solution)? Is it 2008 again? We live in a world where other frameworks have been solving such problems for many years. The `ConstraintLayout` has been for ages in Android Framework which solves this problem at ease.

It clearly showcases the problem that Flutter framework needs to grow a bit more mature. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyTimeLine extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _TimeLineState createState() => _TimeLineState();
 }

class _TimeLineState extends State<MyTimeLine> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Padding(
  padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
  child: new Column(
    children: <Widget>[
         IntrinsicHeight(
        child: new Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Wrap(
              direction: Axis.vertical,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  width: 30.0,
                  child: new Center(
                    child: new Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Padding(
                          padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
                          child: new Container(
                              margin:
                                  new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0),
                              height: double.infinity,
                              width: 1.0,
                              color: Colors.deepOrange),
                        ),
                        new Container(
                          padding: new EdgeInsets.only(),
                          child: new Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.white),
                          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                              color: new Color(0xff00c6ff),
                              shape: BoxShape.circle),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            new Expanded(
              child: new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Padding(
                    padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 5.0),
                    child: new Text(
                      'Header Text',
                      style: new TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          color: Colors.deepOrange,
                          fontSize: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  new Padding(
                    padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 5.0),
                    child: new Text(
                        'Lorem ipsum description here description here Lorem ipsum description here description here Lorem ipsum description here Lorem ipsum description here description here Lorem ipsum description here description here Lorem ipsum description here description here Lorem ipsum description here description here Lorem ipsum description here description here Lorem ipsum description here description here Lorem ipsum description here description here Lorem ipsum description here description here Lorem ipsum description here description here Lorem ipsum description here description here '),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: A glance of the pub]

Check out this pub.
https://pub.dev/packages/timeline_widget

It helps create beautiful timeline ui with everything customised. Also available in left right and center aligned options. This is an example of how to use it!

```
TimelineView(
  align: TimelineAlign.rightAlign,
  lineWidth: 4,
  lineColor: Colors.deepOrange,
  imageBorderColor: Colors.deepOrange,
  image: [
    Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Image.asset("assets/pre-breakfast-image.png")),
    Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Image.asset("assets/breakfast-image.png")),
    Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Image.asset("assets/pre-lunch-image.png")),
    Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Image.asset("assets/lunch-image.png")),
    Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Image.asset("assets/evening-snack-image.png")),
    Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Image.asset("assets/dinner-image.png")),
  ],
  height: 150,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  imageHeight: 50,
  children: [
    Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
        child: _widgetWeather(20, 71, 31)),
    Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
        child: _widgetWeather(15, 75, 55)),
    Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
        child: _widgetWeather(25, 73, 30)),
    Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
        child: _widgetWeather(22, 65, 35)),
    Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
        child: _widgetWeather(21, 55, 32)),
    Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
        child: _widgetWeather(20, 65, 35)),
  ],
),
```

Comment: I love that you took a screenshot while on the phone hhahaha

Answer (score 0):

you can use flutter_timeline, both body and indicator, lines are customizable.

https://github.com/softmarshmallow/flutter-timeline

this is the latest, supported package out there for flutter.
[image]