# What is the name of these dots figure of input?

Tags: user-interface, input, flutter

What are these dots behind text inputs?

I want it to search if there is package can do it to save time

[image: timeline]

Comment: https://ibb.co/fQk1j9Z **PAGE DESIGN**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call them timeline

Checkout https://pub.dev/packages/timeline_list

You can also checkout this code snippet https://stackoverflow.com/a/50665520/6207294