# Expand widget to match parent height inside the row in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create below UI[image]

How to draw a line between widget, If try to expand the column line inside the row it gives error of infinity height

//Below some code not able to post all the code.

```
ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: <Widget>[
                new _Row(
                  label: "1",
                  body:
                      "Screening: We will screen your current portfolio to check your Portfolio's health.",
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16,
                ),
              ],
            ),


class _Row extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final String body;

  const _Row({Key key, this.label, this.body});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: 28,
          height: 28,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xff76587b).withOpacity(0.5),
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              label,
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 16,
        ),
        Flexible(
          child: Text(
            body,
            style: kModelTargetCARGTInactiveTextLabel.copyWith(
                color: Colors.black, height: 1.4),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

In this code line between bullet points not visible. I tried may option but it not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter: Create a timeline UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49635381/flutter-create-a-timeline-ui)

Comment: Also you can customize `stepper` widget

Comment: I customized the stepper as per requirement